# Optimal assignment of items from the list of possible values

Tags: algorithm

I have structure, that looks like this:

- slot_1 (1 item required): [2,3,5,7],
- slot_2 (2 items required): [1,2]
- slot_3 (2 items required): [3,7,8]
- slot_4 (1 item required): [3]

Each slot have array of items ids, which are allowed to be inputted into it. Items cannot be duplicated across slots. Every slot has strict number of required items.

Is there any algorithm I can use to find optimal fill for those slots?

Comment: when in doubt: use brute force with back tracking.

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem.

Comment: what are the numbers in brackets? The allowed ids? Which items are to be distributed among the slots? What is "optimal"?

Comment: Is this some sort of assignment or a real-world problem?

Comment: Spread them evenly across all slots?

Comment: Please specify your problem more clearly and provide an example of what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Jasper It's basically employees assignment for specific shifts. So item=employee, and slot=shift.

Comment: @user5132946 So what would make any solution optimal?

Comment: @Glubus I probably misused the word 'optimal'. My goal is to find any fill, that will satisfy amount of items (employees) required, on the conditions mentioned in question.

Comment: could you show one (or better, several) possible good filling, to make the things clear ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reminds me of solving a sodoku puzzle by the form of a computer algorithm. The way I'd solve it is by the means of backtracking, starting with the slots with the least amount of options.

Step 1: Sort your slots by amount of options from least to highest.

Step 2: Give every slot a value from his list of options (by the order you found in step 1)

Step 2.1 If you find that a slot has no valid options, because earlier slots have taken its last option, remove all choices until you reach the slot that had the needed value, and choose another one (one that has not already been chosen), and go back to step 2. Note that the backtracking resets all choices and values for the slots that are higher in the sorted list than the slot you end up changing.

Step 3.1 If you find that all slots have values, return the configuration as a valid solution.

Step 3.2 If you find that a slot has tried out all his options and still needs to change its value because of step 2.1, return false as there is no valid solution for the specified domain.